# jQuery AJAX not working on production server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

This is my first post on here. Any help would be awesome. I'm trying to call a vb.NET subroutine from my aspx page using jQuery and AJAX. When I run the page from VS 2008 on my PC (Windows XP SP2), it works great. When I copy the site to the production server Windows Server 2008 , it doesn't do anything. No errors or anything. I've tried debugging with IE's script debugger. I've been trying to figure this out for days and am coming up with nothing.

Here is the script:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function AjaxTest() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "Test.aspx/AjaxTestSub",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Didn't work!");
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert("Worked!");
    }
</script>
```

And here is the simple subroutine:

```
<WebMethod()> Public Shared Sub AddPOToTrailer()
    MsgBox("Made it to Subroutine!")
End Sub
```

I'm sure I left a bunch of information out, so please ask if you can think of anything that might help.

Comment: It looks like you're using a relative URL for the Test.aspx page reference. Is that page at the same location on the server as it is in your development environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `MsgBox()` from server-side code.
Get rid of that call and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test that a call is returning data you can use Response.Write rather than MsgBox.  Keep in mind that you will likely need to use Response.Clear and Response.Flush depending on how you are managing your code behind.  If it is an HttpHandler or Web Service call you should be fine, but if you are calling a web page it will render the page content (i.e. HTML) if you do not instruct the server to stop with a Response.End once you have written your content to the Output Stream.

Hope this helps.